# Import strings with line terminator from csv to dask dataframe

Tags: python, csv, import, dask

I have a csv with strings containing line terminator I can import with panda with this code :

```
df_desc = pd.read_csv(import_desc, sep="|")
```

But when I try to import it in a dask dataframe :

```
import dask.dataframe as ddf  
import_info = "data/info.csv"  
df_desc = ddf.read_csv(import_desc, sep="|", blocksize=None, dtype='str')
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1578, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1015, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/data_extraction_dask.py", line 10, in <module>
    df_desc = ddf.read_table(import_desc, sep="|", blocksize=None, dtype='str')
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/csv.py", line 323, in read
    **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/csv.py", line 243, in read_pandas
    head = reader(BytesIO(b_sample), **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 655, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 411, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 982, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1719, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 890, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:10862)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 912, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:11138)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 966, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:11884)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 953, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:11755)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2184, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:28765)
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 130
```

The documentation mention :

> It should also be noted that this function may fail if a CSV file
>   includes quoted strings that contain the line terminator. To get
>   around this you can specify blocksize=None to not split files into
>   multiple partitions, at the cost of reduced parallelism.

That's why I used blocksize=None but this function use a sampling strategy that use the first bytes of the file to determine the type of columns and , I think, generate this error.

I can't skip the samping step even by indicating the type with dtypes.

Is there any workaround ?

Comment: Read with `pandas` then convert to `dask` with `from_pandas(df)`.